Looking for resources on how to best design structures for storing and editing page data
Apologies for the broad question, but most of my experience has been working with using older versions of Sitecore, primarily Web forms based projects and only using the Content Editor. General page template designs were normally an Item with specific fields that would be used for rendering given chunks of data (title, content block, header, etc) and required content editors to know fairly good HTML to modify a content block field which would then display the majority of the page content in a pleasing fashion.
I'm working with a team trying to "move up" to Sitecore 9.2 and create MVC based projects that are easier for their content editors to add and modify different types of content using the experience editor and arrange it how they like.
I have a baseline understanding of how to make the needed renderings and different views, but in trying to determine the best way to architect storing the underlying data for a given control I'm having a bit of a hard time finding good resources for best practices.  Assigning data sources to rendering seems to work fine, but feels a bit of a kludge.
I feel like a content editor should be able to insert a "text" rendering for example, the underlying datasource is created and assigned to it, and the editor can just click in the newly added rendering and start typing away, but I haven't been able to find resources that talk about this.  I would appreciate and pointers others have towards good resource or even training bits, I have been extensively going through SitecoreDiaries and the Pluralsight courses already.

Check out the Helix architecture. https://helix.sitecore.com/ Otherwise, I'd encourage you to post this question in Sitecore Slack instead of here.

SXA has components that are similar to what you are referring to here. E.g. SXA has a Rich Text component that adds the datasource automatically when you drag and drop the component from the Toolbox. There are also Reusable components, which will ask you to select the datasource.

I will request you to move to latest version of Sitecore and have a look at SXA datasource https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/data-sources.html and also list of available SXA components https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/101/sitecore-experience-accelerator/components.html

Thank you for the input so far!  I do not think we have a license for SXA with this instance, it is an extra component you need to pay for I think.  I will also try and join the Sitecore Slack.
